# Sending test mails locally

Tags: 7, emails

I can't test sending emails with Drupal 7 on my local host. I have been searching for some solutions for more than 10 days but unfortunately the problem still exists.

Any help?

Comment: You can use [SMTP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module for testing emails from localhost. This should work consistently even when you migrate the site to a live server.

Comment: I've tried this solution actually but it didn't work for me. I also tried PHPMailer. I have tried to use also a "sendmail.exe" although I am on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Maillog](https://www.drupal.org/project/maillog) to test emails locally.

> Maillog provides an easy possibility to log all Mails for debugging
>   purposes. It's possible to prevent the mails to being sent, so there
>   is no need for an extra mail server to test the mail functionality of
>   other modules or the drupal core. Additionally you can immediately
>   display the mail through the devel dpm() facility.

Answer (score 0):

Use [toolheap](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) which will work for windows. Add SMTP module and set in configuration of

**SMTP Authentication support >> SMTP SERVER SETTINGS**

SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com

SMTP port: 465

Use encrypted protocol: Use SSL

**SMTP Authentication support >> SMTP AUTHENTICATION**

Username: --emailid--

Password: --password--

Click SEND TEST E-MAIL.. Then Save. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows using something like xampp, you can do this without using the drupal [smtp](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module:

1. edit your sendmail.ini
2. you will then need to set variables like:
   smtp_server=
   smtp_port=465
   smtp_ssl=auto
   auth_username=....
   auth_password=...
3. edit your php.ini and uncomment out sendmail line, for instance:

   sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

Then it should work once apache is restarted.